# How to prove this decomposition of $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I'm reading definition of conditional expectation from a lecture note:

> [image]

the the author presents a proposition:

> [image]

I'm able to prove that $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}}\right]}{\mathbb{P}\left[\Lambda_{i}\right]} \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}}$ satisfies **CE1**, but failed to prove that it satisfies **CE2**. Below is my attempt. Let $A \in \mathcal G$, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
& \int_A \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}}\right]}{\mathbb{P}\left[\Lambda_{i}\right]} \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}} \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb P &&= \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \int_A  \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}}\right]}{\mathbb{P}\left[\Lambda_{i}\right]} \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}} \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb P\\ = & \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \int_A  \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}}\right]}{\mathbb{P}\left[\Lambda_{i}\right]} \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}} \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb P &&= \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{A \cap \Lambda_{i}}  \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}}\right]}{\mathbb{P}\left[\Lambda_{i}\right]} \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb P \\
=& \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}}\right]}{\mathbb{P}\left[\Lambda_{i}\right]} \int_{A \cap \Lambda_{i}}   \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb P &&= \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X \textbf{1}_{\Lambda_{i}}\right]}{\mathbb{P}\left[\Lambda_{i}\right]}  \mathbb P [A \cap \Lambda_{i}] \\
 =& \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\mathbb P [A \cap \Lambda_{i}]}{\mathbb{P}\left[\Lambda_{i}\right]} \int_{\Lambda_{i}} X  \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb P
\end{aligned}$$

Could you please help me to proceed? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have to use the fact that $\mathcal G$ is generated by a partition: the set $A$ is of the form $\bigcup_{j\in J}\Lambda_j$ for some subset $J$ of $\mathbb N$. 
Then $\mathbb P[A\cap \Lambda_i]/\mathbb P[\Lambda_i]$ is either zero or one, according to the case where $i\in J$ or not. We end up with $\sum_{i\in J}\int_{\Lambda_j}X\mathrm dP$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your enlightening answer ;)